# How to make a square box left aligned in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a square box aligned at the left side in Bootstrap but I am a little bit confused how to do it using well-container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="well pull-left">...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response a lot and how can i adjust the width of that ?

Comment: You can change class col and manipulate your div's width. See grid system on bootstrap website.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

use any image and apply **class="pull-left"**